# Distributed Cache feature in YARN

Tags: hadoop

Currently i am using MAP-REDUCE YARN framework. And using hadoop in pseudo distributed mode.
I want to use "Distributed Cache" feature here to add some files to cache and use it in my map function. How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to add files to distributed cache:**

- Using hadoop option

.

```
hadoop jar <application jar> <main class> <input> <output> -files <absolute path to distributed cache file>
```

- using Distributed cache API:

.

```
job.addCacheFile(uri);
```

hadoop -files option or Distributed cache API copies the cache files to all the task nodes and make it available for mapper/ reducer during execution.

**How to access distributed cache:**

Override setup method in Mapper/ reducer and call getCacheFiles from context.
Sample code below:

```
    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Path[] localPaths = context.getCacheFiles();
        if (localPaths.length == 0) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Distributed cache file not found.");
        }
        File localFile = new File(localPaths[0].toString());
        // code to process cache file

    }
```

context.getCacheFiles method returns an URI array of the files set in the Configuration.

Comment: It is throwing "filenotfound execption". please help me with this.

Comment: Please have a look at distributed cache implementation example: https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/blob/master/ch08/src/main/java/MaxTemperatureByStationNameUsingDistributedCacheFileApi.java

Comment: @VijayInnamuri That is a dead link. Can you post a new one?

Comment: This link is from Tom's Book, from the Fourth Edition: https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/blob/master/ch09-mr-features/src/main/java/MaxTemperatureByStationNameUsingDistributedCacheFile.java